# Visual Studio and File not Found Warnings with MVC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

In Visual Studio warning I have the following errors in my forms for my view with HTML like:

`<form id="hitgraph" action="/HitResponseGraph" method="get">`

/HitResponseGraph is a view in MVC and the form works fine. How do inform Visual studio that this view exists so it doesn't warn on this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using @using(Html.BeginForm()) ?

Comment: I was thinking the same use the helper methods to make your views reusable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem when I moved a project from a development system to a live server.
While I first thought that Html.BeginForm() was little more than a macro to build a form tag, it turns out that its use is the solution -- it internally corrected the relative paths.